# Play 2 sounds one after the other using AudioToolbox

Tags: audio, button, playback, audiotoolbox

I have this sound playing after pressing one button using AudioToolbox.

```
-(void) onButtonPressSound {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"m4a"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

}
```

how can i make it play 2 sounds instead of one, one after the other, after pressing this button?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this:
first one: for a lazy one like me :)
Take a sound which plays 2 sounds one after other .
Another One:

```
SystemSoundID receiveMessageSound1;
SystemSoundID receiveMessageSound2;
NSString *sendPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Music1" ofType:@"wav"];
            CFURLRef baseURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:sendPath];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(baseURL, &receiveMessageSound1);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(receiveMessageSound1);
NSString *sendPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Music2" ofType:@"wav"];
            baseURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:sendPath2];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(baseURL, &receiveMessageSound2);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(receiveMessageSound2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i get the following errors "redefinition of sendPath" (i modified it to sendPath2, it's ok), and "redefinion of base URL" - this i cannot change.

Comment: @Mihai: I have edited check it once, and accept the answer if solved :)

Comment: thanks vishwa, i still get it with both sounds one on top of the other. i was looking to get them one after another.

Comment: you can have a sleep between two sounds as: sleep(1);